# Should "component" functions in Om be called directly?

Tags: reactjs, om

As I'm only starting to fully understand, `om.core/build` and `om.next`'s factory functions return React element objects, which refer to component functions/classes, and [the actual component is only instantiated later by React's reconciler](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html). That is, `(om.core/build some-component data)` doesn't actually call `some-component` immediately.

However, we often represent simple, "stateless" components as just functions which take props and return a React element. In the (pure) React world, you'd use one of these functions like a component class, as `React.createElement(AStatelessComponent, {some: "props"})`, or more conveniently in JSX as `<AStatelessComponent some="props" />`. Those too return a React element which references `AStatelessComponent`, which won't actually be called until later.

But in Om, when we have a simple component like this (and by "we" I mean me and my team, at least), we call the function directly. Thus,

```
(render [this]
  (om/div {}
      (a-stateless-component {:some "data"})))
```

Here, `a-stateless-component` *is* called immediately, and whatever it returns is inserted directly into the div, rather than being substituted later by the React reconciler.

Is there a preferred way to `React.createElement` in Om? Or is it preferred to just call functions like this directly, even though it skips creating a component instance in the render tree?

Answer (score 0):

In Om, if you want to instantiate a stateless component you need to call `js/React.createElement` directly.

Why you would want to do that depends:

1. if you call `React.createElement` you get a "tracked" instance in React's reconciler
2. if you don't, you get inlining but the stateless component now cannot be distinguished from its parent in React's render tree.

EDIT: I just realized that `om.next/factory` is permissive enough that it allows you to instantiate the stateless components you were talking about. So you can achieve what you want both by calling `js/React.createElement` directly on a function of props, or by calling `om.next/factory` with that same function as argument.

Here's a working example. The following code:

```
((om/factory #(dom/div nil "Hello, World")))
```

results in the following component (in React's devtools):

[image: stateless component]